# Magento 1.9 Call to a member function isPathAllowed() on a non-object

Tags: email, magento

I'm getting this error if I use "{{config path}}" in the content of any transactional emails like {{config path='trans_email/ident_support/email'}}.

Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by a third party extension, one such extension is Extendware_EWImageOpt. Check if you have it and also clear the cache

Comment: I don't have that extension installed in my, however, I've got a list of the possible extensions that could cause the error:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LHJL6D6xm3vD349DJsDF88FBI_6PZvx_u3FioC_1-rg/edit#gid=0

I tried to disable each one of the extension that was installed in my instance but still the error is still there.